# How can I fetch a datapoint at certain time every day in Graphite?

Tags: graphite, grafana, datapoint, whisper

I have a series of data that increases by time and resets to zero at 18:00 every day.  How can I make a Graphite plot that only contains datapoints at 17:59 in the last 30 days?

I have tried `summarize(1d, max, false)`, but it by default bins data into buckets that are calculated by rounding to the nearest interval to current time. So I cannot specify the beginning time of each bucket to be 18:00.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything that exactly matches what you want. There are functions like timeSlice and timeStack but they do not really fit.

An alternative is to use the graphite function [nonNegativeDerivative](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.nonNegativeDerivative). It ignores when counters are reset to zero and only shows counter increments.